# C# vs C: Organizing Data Structures

Tags: c#, struct

I want to define a data struct which I can access byte wise. In other words: I want to transfer an object of a specific data structure byte wise.

The goal is to have a high level access (access by name) to the data as well as a low level access that is only byte wise.

I do have a data transfer protocol that has a specific packet format (Header, Payload, CRC,... even bit definitions. Eventually the entire packet is 32-bit aligned).

In "C" I define a struct and access an object of this struct byte wise by casting that object into a byte array. I.e.:

```
/* C-Code */
typedef struct
{
    int16_t a;
    int8_t b;

    /* And a bit-wise definition to make thinks really cool */
    int8_t bit_0   : 1;
    int8_t bit_1_7 : 7;

    /* (Total size is 4 bytes i.e. 32-bit aligned) */
} MY_STRUCT_t;
```

"my_struct" should now be read byte wise to e.g. transfer it to some where: 
The inexpressive way:

```
/* C-Code */
void main(void)
{
    MY_STRUCT_t my_struct;

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < sizeof(my_struct); i++)
    {
        Transfer_Byte( *((uint8_t *) &my_struct) + i);
    }
}
```

Or to make it more expressive i will define the following "union" as well:

```
/* C-Code */
typedef union
{
    MY_STRUCT_t data;
    uint8_t bytes[sizeof(MY_STRUCT_t)];
} MY_STRUCT_u;
```

and do it this way:

```
/* C-Code */
void main(void)
{
    MY_STRUCT_u my_struct; // object of the union this time!

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < sizeof(my_struct); i++)
    {
        Transfer_Byte(my_struct.bytes[i]);
    }
}
```

**Question**

- How do I do this in C#? What is your suggestion? Or could you give me a hint how to solve this?

Cheers

Comment: Maybe start from [C# docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-classes-structures-and-unions) ? It's a big and broad topic.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thx for your quick answers! 
"StructLayoutAttribute.Pack Field" is pretty much what I was looking for! Thx!!

Comment: @Access Denied: you may copy paste your input as "answer" so I can define it as answer.

Comment: Glad that the link was helpful. Added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Low-Level access there is a [StructLayoutAttribute.Pack Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=netframework-4.8) in conjunction with [FieldOffsetAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

With these attributes you can manage how bytes are aligned in the structure.

Answer (score 2):

For C# you're best to implement a "ToByte" and "FromByte" function and process the fields directly to ensure that the data is ordered in the manner that you wish.

**BTW**. I cautious using the struct union trick unless your packing and unpacking on the same platform and executable as the byte order is platform and compiler dependent for multibyte values.